# How to change number of reserved bytes in assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've just started learning assembly and I want to know how to change the number of reserved bytes, if possible at all.

I've created the following code that will create a right triangle of decreasing length based on the `max` variable at the bottom. However, in order to make sure I don't reserve excess bytes, I want to calculate it (which I believe works in `calculateBytes`), then reserve those bytes.

If this is not possible, please explain. Would there be an alternative to help make this work if not?

```
bits 64

global  _start

section .text
    _start:     
        mov        rdx, output
        mov        r8, max
        mov        r9, r8
        mov        r10, r8
        mov        r11, r8

    calculateBytes:
        add        r11, r10
        dec        r10
        jnz        calculateBytes

    line:
        mov        byte [rdx], '*'
        inc        rdx
        dec        r9
        
        jnz        line

    lineDone:
        mov        byte [rdx], 10
        inc        rdx
        dec        r8
        mov        r9, r8
        jnz        line
        
    done:
        mov        rax, 1 ; initiate writing
        mov        rdi, 1 ; to stdout
        mov        rsi, output; use output
        mov        rdx, size ; with this size
        syscall
        mov        rax, 60
        xor        rdi, rdi
        syscall

section .bss
    size      equ     1000
    output    resb    size
    max       equ     30
```

Comment: The only place you're reserving any bytes is `output    resb    size`.  `resb` requires an assemble-time constant size.  If you want to use `size equ max * max` or `max * (max+1)/2` or whatever, you can just write it that way: the assembler is perfectly capable of evaluating expressions at assemble time.  If you wanted to multiply at run-time, use `imul r11, r11`, not a loop!  But you don't use your `r11` result anywhere so IDK what you think it's accomplishing, or where you wanted to reserve space.

Comment: @PeterCordes I literally just started learning assembly today. I don't have a full understanding of the different registers and how the reserved bytes work. I'm probably wrong, but the way I understand it, output contains the n-number of bytes that is then given to rdx who can "iterate" through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
calculateBytes:
    add        r11, r8
    dec        r10
    jnz        calculateBytes
```

This produces `max * (max + 1)` which is too much.
What you want is (1st number is asterisks, 2nd number is newline):

```
(30 + 1) + (29 + 1) + (28 + 1) ... (2 + 1) + (1 + 1)
```

In assembly:

```
calculateBytes:
    add        r11, r10
    dec        r10
    jnz        calculateBytes

    ...

    mov        rdx, r11
    syscall
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to update the r8. I added the `mov` and `syscall`, but now it's running infinitely for some reason. Also, why is syscall needed?

Comment: @12944qwerty If you don't make a `write()` system call, nothing will get written to stdout.  Without an exit system call, you can only exit by crashing (e.g. doing something that will raise a SIGSEGV).

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood where those two opcodes were supposed to be. I thought they were still in the `calculateBytes` part and not the `done` part. Still, don't I need to tell `rdx` that there is a certain number of bytes that it has been reserved?

Comment: @Sep: There's a well-known closed form formula for the sum of an integer series, `n * (n+1)/2`.  Or in this case, from 2 to max+1 (an extra 1 for every line), `size equ max * (max+1)/2 + max`.  If you did have a runtime-variable length, you could use `lea rdx, [r8+1]` / `imul rdx, r8` / `shr rdx, 1`.  (Overflow of the product before the right shift isn't a concern in this case: the maximum usable array length is less than 64-bit on x86-64, since virtual addresses are only 57-bit at most.)

Comment: Your program has reserved a 1000-byte buffer at the address *output*. That's fine. What the system call (that writes on the screen) needs, is the *actual number of characters to write* and that is what was calculated in R11.

Comment: @12944qwerty: Yes, RAX=1 / `syscall` is `write` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), where `size_t len` goes in RDX.  That's exactly what Sep is showing, that you compute the total length for your `write` system call and put that length in RDX.  That's separate from the number of bytes reserved in the buffer with `resb 1000`; you can use less than the space reserved, but you can't use more.

Comment: Hm, but what happened to the 1000 reserved bytes? They can't be used elsewhere can they?

Comment: Those 1000 bytes are what is called a **multi-purpose buffer**. As the name suggests, you can re-use it many times.

Comment: @12944qwerty: The 1000 reserved bytes are your output buffer, like C `static char buf[size];`.  But you only want to tell `write` to copy from the part of that space where you actually put `'*'` and newline characters, so `write(1, buf, computed_size)` not `write(1, buf, sizeof(buf))`; that would include a bunch of `0` bytes at the end.  (Pipe into `hexdump -C` or redirect to a file, or use `strace ./a.out` to see exactly what output your program produces.  `00` ASCII NUL prints as zero width on a terminal).  You can of course use that same static buffer earlier or later for other things.